# unable to connect to Mongodb using HibernateOGM

Tags: java, hibernate, mongodb, hibernate-ogm

I want to use HibernateOGM to interact with MongoDB. I have an `cfg.xml` file like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
      <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider">mongodb</property>
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.grid_dialect">org.hibernate.ogm.dialect.MongoDBDialect</property>
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.database">rcfdb</property>
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host">127.0.0.1</property>
      <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port">27017</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
      <mapping resource="hibernate-contact.hbm.xml"/>    
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have also wrote my POJO class, and  in the main class I want to populate the database in the mongodb with this code, but I am not able to do this job and I get these line of Infos, how can I solve that:

```
Session session=null;
            OgmConfiguration cfgogm=new OgmConfiguration();
            SessionFactory sessionfactory= cfgogm.buildSessionFactory();
            session=sessionfactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            System.out.println("Populating the database...");
            Contact cnt=new Contact();
            cnt.setFirstname("Blabla");
            cnt.setLastname("Blabla");
            cnt.setEmail("blabla");
            session.save(cnt);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("Done... :)");
```

I have no output with this code, and also no exceptions

INFO Lines:
[image]

This is the structure of my project:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `MongoDBDialect` in the configuration file. But on the console log, you are getting `NoopDialect` on `HHH000400`.
And in the next line, you are getting `connection was null`.
And the last line is, `Unable to create requested service`.

Comment: yes, but as uo said I have defined it in my configuration file, Do you know, how can I solve my problem?

Comment: I think, your configuration file is not getting detected.

Comment: can you paste your project structure.

Comment: What should I post exactly?

Comment: your project tree structure.

Comment: Put out `.cfg.xml` and `.hbm.xml` outside `<default package>`.

Comment: Ok, but now I have another error:Failed to execute goal on project HibernateOGM_MongoDB:` Could not resolve dependencies for project hogm:HibernateOGM_MongoDB:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0, javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B: Failure to find javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0 in https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-public-repository-group has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]...`

Comment: Some `jars` are missing. Download them and put them into your project.

Comment: I did it, but the problem still exists as I mentioned in my post

Comment: In your `pom.xml`, specify these dependencies and `update` your project using maven.

Comment: I am new in Maven, could you please tell me what should I excatly do? I am using netbeans7.3 I have just a little bit google it but I didn't understand what should I do

Comment: Read about adding `dependencies` in `maven`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, I did It but the problem still exist, as you mentioned, I think the Maven doesn't recognize my hibernateogm, because, if I modify the `pom.xml` I dont get any hint from Netbeans, what I see are only `hibernate` and not `hibernate.ogm`. I have copied and paste the code in in `pom.xml`

Comment: Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Right click on your project, go to maven and click `update` there.

Comment: I did it but I dont have Update option

Answer (score 0):

hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port -> hibernate.ogm.datastore.port

I puzzled over this for two days